# Can jboss snmp adapter(snmp agent) be extended to support my defined MIB?

Tags: jboss, jmx, snmp

I have our own MIB files, and I know in many cases, I have to write snmp agent to support my own MIB.

But this time, I think if I can make jboss snmp adapter(JBossSNMPAdapter) to support my MIB, it will be much easier. So that, through jboss snmp adapter, I can query by its oid.
I know JBossSNMPAdapter already suppport MIB-II.

**I wonder if jboss snmp adapter can suppport user defined MIB so that user can query by oid?** And how to configure? Are there some materials about this (jboss snmp adapter)?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is quite straightforward to do.

Inside the `snmp-agent.sar` directory, you'll see a file called `attributes.xml`. This file associates SNMP OIDs with JMX attributes.

So for each item in your MIB, you need to expose that information via a JMX MBean, and then add the OID->JMX association to `attributes.xml`.

The agent itself neither knows nor cares about your MIB, so you need to be careful to specify the OIDs in `attributes.xml` properly.

Comment: skaffman, thanks for your help! :-)It makes me understand the mechanism well. It seems I will need to find out how to expose that information via a JMX MBean.

Comment: skaffman, thanks again for your help. your information is very valuable to me. With your help, I solved the problem, yes, snmp-adapter can be extended just follow your way. You are very helpful :-)